# BizTalk with WCF service - null object in service

Tags: web-services, namespaces, biztalk, nullreferenceexception

I have a ASP.NET Webservice and am trying to call it from the BizTalk. Now I've managed for the webservice to actually be entered, but the object can't be mapped and always returns NULL. After trying and testing I finally found out that the one thing that makes it fail the mapping is the namespace on the root node. Now I have no clue how I can remove that namespace or would it be better to somehow try to adjust the webservice to use the namespace?

My Service Method:

```
public bool CreateBasket(Basket basket)
        {
            if(basket == null)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Basket could not be mapped on the service."));

            _entities.AddToBaskets(basket);

            foreach (var item in basket.Items)
            {
                _entities.AddToItems(item);
            }

            return _entities.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }
```

The basket object is created by the Entity Model.

This call works:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<CreateBasket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<basket xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OC.SampleCustomer.WCFService" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<ns0:BillingId>5</ns0:BillingId>
```

This call doesn't work:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<CreateBasket xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns0:basket xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OC.SampleCustomer.WCFService" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<ns0:BillingId>5</ns0:BillingId>
```

*Edit*
The BizTalk recieves the error I throw in my service method in the recieve body. So my error message on the biztalk server is "Basket could not be mapped on the service."

Comment: Are you using "Add Service Reference" to the service? Is the service a asmx service?

Comment: Yep I have a Service Reference to the service, but its a svc service.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your exact problem is. Can you post you error message

Comment: I added the code snippet which throws the error up in my original post

Comment: How are you constructing the service request message?

Comment: it's generated by the biztalk or what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Before you send your service request you need to construct the message. Either you are doing this in a transform, a message assignment (from inside an orchestration), or you are doing this manually and dropping the message in somewhere.

Comment: well I have a file that I drop into a folder manually, which the biztalk gets and maps according to the orchestration

Answer (score 2):

I gave up on the entity framework and created my own objects with defined namespaces for the WCF service and now it works. Thanks for the help, I'll keep playing around with it till I understand more =)